update Select option value using useState In ReactJs
I have a full stack pizza system: Asp net core Web api and React. When customers are ordering, they cant choose Delivery or Collection in which I used Select options tag to achieve do it. When a user chooses "Collection", address1, address2, street and postCode are hidden from the user and are submitted as "" to the database.
The problem is that I cannot update the order from "Collection" to "Delivery" or vice versa. When I click on Edit, it goes to the Edit page and the value of deliveryOption is not set to the select option. I used defaultValue={order.deliverOption}, value={order.deliverOption} and selected={order.deliveryOption} but nothing worked. I can update everything else.
What I want is to update from Collection to Delivery and full address, and from Delivery to Collection by clearing existing values of full address.
Here is the select option handler for the component. Can't add full code because of format errors. I don't know this is happening but I think it is the comments I added.
const [showHide, setShowHide] = useState("");
const handleShowHide = (e) => {
const getOptions = e.target.value;

setShowHide(getOptions);
if (getOptions === "Collection") {
  setAddress1(" ");
  setAddress2(" ");
  setStreet(" ");
  setPostCode(" ");
  setOrder({ ...order, address1: setAddress1("")})
  setOrder({ ...order, address2:setAddress1("")})
  setOrder({ ...order, street: setAddress1("")})
  setOrder({ ...order, postCode: setAddress1("")})
  
}

};
Update method:
const [order, setOrder] = useState({});

const updateOrder = (e) => {
OrderService.updateOrder(orderId, menuId, order)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(menu);
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Upating order details",
      text: "Done",
      icon: "success",
    });
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));

navigate("/orders");

};
Get order method from backend. It correctly shows Collection or Delivery when I logged it to the console.
const getOrder = (orderId, menuId) => {
OrderService.getOrderById(orderId, menuId).then((res) => {
  
  setOrder(res.data);
  setOrderTotal(order.total);
  console.log(res.data);

});

};
UI portion
  <h3 className="text-center">Edit Your Order</h3>
  <div className="container min-vh-10  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <form >
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="form-controler">Order Id</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="number"
          value={orderId}
          readOnly
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="form-controler">Menu Id</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="number"
          value={menuId}
          readOnly
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
          Delivery Option
        </label>
        <select
          defaultValue={order.deliverOption}
          
          className="form-control"
          onClick={(e) => handleShowHide(e)}
          onChange={(e) => setOrder({ ...order, deliverOption: e.target.value })}
        >
          <input
            className="form-control"
            
          />
          <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
          <option value="Collection">Collection</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
          Quantity
        </label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          value={order.quantity}
          onInput={(e) => setOrderTotal(menu.price * e.target.value)}
          onChange={(e) => setOrder({ ...order, quantity: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
          Phone Number
        </label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          value={order.phoneNumber}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setOrder({ ...order, phoneNumber: e.target.value })
          }
        />
      </div>

      {showHide === "Delivery" && (
        <>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
              Address1
            </label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              value={order.address1}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setOrder({ ...order, address1: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
              Address 2
            </label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              value={order.address2}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setOrder({ ...order, address2: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
              Street
            </label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              value={order.street}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setOrder({ ...order, street: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
              Post Code
            </label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              value={order.postCode}
              
                onChange={(e) =>
                  setOrder({ ...order, 
                    postCode: e.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>
        </>
      )}

      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="" className="input-label">
          Total
        </label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="number"
          id="AllOrderTotal"
          value={orderTotal}
          readonly
        />
      </div>

      <button
        className="btn btn-primary mb-3 w-100 "
        onClick={(e) => updateOrder(orderId, menu.id, order)}
      >
        Update Order
      </button>

      <button
        className="btn btn-primary mb-3  w-100 "
        onClick={(e) => GoBackToOrders()}
      >
        Go Back To Orders
      </button>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary mb-3 w-100 "
        onClick={(e) => GoBackToMenus()}
      >
        Go Back To Menus
      </button>

      
    </form>
  </div>
</>

);
};
export default withRouter(EditOrder);

You can update your EditOrder.js file like below, and here is my test result.
From Collection to Delivery


From Delivery to  Collection


EditOrder.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"; 

const EditOrder = () => {
  const { id } = useParams(); 
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
  const [showHide, setShowHide] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://localhost:7251/api/order/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setOrder(response.data);
        setShowHide(response.data.deliverOption);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("There was an error fetching the order!", error);
      });
  }, [id]);

  const handleShowHide = (e) => {
    const getOptions = e.target.value;
    setShowHide(getOptions);

    if (getOptions === "Collection") {
      setOrder({
        ...order,
        deliverOption: getOptions,
        address1: "",
        address2: "",
        street: "",
        postCode: "",
      });
    } else {
      setOrder({
        ...order,
        deliverOption: getOptions,
      });
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setOrder({
      ...order,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const updateOrder = () => {
    axios
      .put(`https://localhost:7251/api/order/${order.id}`, order)
      .then((response) => {
        alert("Order updated successfully!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("There was an error updating the order!", error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Edit Your Order</h3>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Delivery Option</label>
          <select value={order.deliverOption} onChange={handleShowHide}>
            <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
            <option value="Collection">Collection</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        {showHide === "Delivery" && (
          <>
            <div>
              <label>Address 1</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="address1"
                value={order.address1}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Address 2</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="address2"
                value={order.address2}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Street</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="street"
                value={order.street}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Post Code</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="postCode"
                value={order.postCode}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </>
        )}

        <div>
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="phoneNumber"
            value={order.phoneNumber}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="quantity"
            value={order.quantity}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={updateOrder}>Update Order</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditOrder;


I copied your code but i cannot set deliveryOption to select option tag. The problem is in the front-end.; the backend works perfectly fine and i tested it with postman. The problem is when I am on Orders` page and click on Edit, it takes me to editOrder page but select option value is always shows  Delivery even if the deliveryOption  is Collection. here is the link to github project  https://github.com/Abdirahman0123/Full-Stack-Pizza-System-/blob/main/frontend/src/components/orders/EditOrder.js
